# Excel: Can custom units for be defined for the CONVERT function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, you can convert inches to feet with `=CONVERT(A1,"in","ft")` (where `A1` contains the number to be converted), or bytes to bits with `=CONVERT(A1,"byte","bit)`. This `CONVERT` function works with excel's predefined units.

Is there a way to define custom units such as "piece" or "dozen" or "tub"? I've been using excel's `"bit"` unit in place of "piece". I'd like to do conversions such as `=CONVERT(3,"dozen","piece")` (the result of evaluation should be 36).

Of course, one could maintain a table of custom units together with their conversions into standard units (e.g. 1 piece = 1 bit, 1 dozen = 12 bits). The conversion could then be taken care of using a modified convert function `=MYCONVERT(3,"dozen","piece")` which would look up the custom units from the table. But is there an elegant way to make the original `CONVERT` function work, avoiding workarounds by simply adding to Excel's list of predefined units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: this doesn't answer your exact question, but it does seek to provide a potential **solution**.

I don't know of any way to do precisely what you ask...  but maybe there is a compromise solution where you can use a UDF and have the UDF first call the worksheet function.  If it works, return the result.  Otherwise, go into your custom function.  This just means you would have to replace all instances of CONVERT with MYCONVERT, which, from my limited vantage point, seems like a reasonable trade-off.

Here is a quick sample of how this might look.

Custom conversion boilerplate:

```
Private Function Factor(Unit As String) As Double

  Select Case LCase(Unit)
    Case "dozen"
      Factor = 12
    Case "dz"
      Factor = 12
    Case "unit"
      Factor = 1
    Case "piece"
      Factor = 1
    Case "each"
      Factor = 1
    Case "ea"
      Factor = 1
    Case "gross"
      Factor = 144
    Case Else
      Factor = 0
  End Select

End Function
```

And your UDF:

```
Function MYCONVERT(Val As Double, FromUnit As String, ToUnit As String) As Variant

  On Error GoTo CUSTOM
  MYCONVERT = WorksheetFunction.CONVERT(Val, FromUnit, ToUnit)
  Exit Function

CUSTOM:
  Dim fromFactor, toFactor As Double
  fromFactor = Factor(FromUnit)
  toFactor = Factor(ToUnit)

  If fromFactor = 0 Or toFactor = 0 Then
    MYCONVERT = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Exit Function
  End If

  MYCONVERT = Val * (fromFactor / toFactor)

End Function
```

And now any of these should work:

```
=MYCONVERT(A1,"in","ft")
=MYCONVERT(3,"dozen","piece")
```